# Setting up OS X-style multi touch gestures on elementary OS

Tags: macbook, gesture

I have elementary OS set up on my 64 GB flash drive. For the last year or so, I've been (very happily) using OS X, and will likely continue to use it for a lot of work that I do.

I'm very comfortable with the OS X multi touch gestures (3 fingers slide up to view all open windows, slide three fingers to move between workspaces, etc), so I want to enable these same exact gestures on elementary OS.

How can I go about doing this?

I know that `touchegg` is the software to use, but I'm not quite sure which commands to actually use — in other words, what the contents of the config file needs to be.

As a bonus question, I'd like two fingers swiping right/left in Chromium to go back and forward. How can I achieve that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I enable multi-touch gestures on a laptop trackpad?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/167/how-can-i-enable-multi-touch-gestures-on-a-laptop-trackpad)

Comment: @PNG I'm looking to get information on how to actually fill out the config file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [show notes](http://simplyelementary.net/post/123309080052/toucheggconf) of the first episode of simply elementary they covered the basic setup of a configuration file of touchegg. Their comments on the script are as follows:

> It’s a very basic configuration that allows you to switch between workspaces and view the multitasking view with three-finger swipes. It is very similar to the default Mac OS X gestures if you are used to them. Note: It assumes that you use natural scrolling (the system default), otherwise the left/right swipe directions might feel backward to you. If you prefer the swipe directions to be reversed you can always modify the file to change the behavior.

You can download the configuration file from the Dropbox of Nathan Dyer [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kld6wciz7x1qa63/touchegg.conf?dl=1). 
I know this only answer part of your questions, but I hope it will help you on your way. Maybe by studying the configuration file you can figure out how to set up the rest you want.

Comment: Does this solution also address "two fingers swiping right/left in Chromium to go back and forward"?

Comment: Unfortunately not.