# touchegg inaction on desktop

Tags: release-freya, applications

I used this [link](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1198/setting-up-os-x-style-multi-touch-gestures-on-elementary-os) to setup the OS X like gestures on my elementary OS 0.3.2 x64bits and it works quite well.

Sadly there's a but... If I use gesture on an opened window it will work, for example I got this entry :

```
<gesture type="DRAG" fingers="3" direction="LEFT">
    <action type="CHANGE_DESKTOP">PREVIOUS</action>
</gesture>
```

It says to slide on the `PREVIOUS` desktop when I triple `DRAG` on the left.

My problem is that touchegg seems to not working without any window, but still working on the top panel (didn't try with the dock)

I've read some topics about it but no one fixed my issue, and others were closed.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by installing nautilus and dconf:
https://elementaryforums.com/index.php?threads/enable-desktop-icons-and-right-click-in-elementaryos-freya.198/#post-232