# Pinch to zoom not working on MacBook Air Mid 2011 running Elementary OS Loki

Tags: release-loki, touchpad, macbook

I am pretty much a newbie with Elementary OS. I really like it so far. It's made my old MacBook fast and pretty stable again.

All my hardware works apart from pinch to zoom on my trackpad. Does Loki support this out of the box, or do I have to set it up myself?

Answer (score 1):

It you're using loki, then Touchegg doesn't work. You should install libinput gestures: https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install Touchegg
Look here for instructions:
[How can I enable multi-touch gestures on a laptop trackpad?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/167/how-can-i-enable-multi-touch-gestures-on-a-laptop-trackpad)

There also an GUI for it: [Touchegg-gce](https://github.com/Raffarti/Touchegg-gce)

Theres also another forum thread about it:
[setting-up-os-x-style-multi-touch-gestures-on-elementary-os](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1198/setting-up-os-x-style-multi-touch-gestures-on-elementary-os)

Comment: Touchegg isn't working for Loki, so libinput gestures should be used!